# Install linux-headers-generic in Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

I want to install  linux-headers-generic in my raspberry pi. But I cannot the package via apt-get

```
 pi@raspberrypi ~/Desktop $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+ #538 PREEMPT Fri Aug 30 20:42:08 BST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

I have installed wheezy-raspbian (i.e 2013-09-25-wheezy-raspbian)

I tried a lot but couldn't find it.

Please help me how can I get it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried installing the linux-headers virtual package, to let the system pick the appropriate version for you?

Comment: linux-headers-virtual package is also not found

Comment: First `sudo apt-get update` next, the package is not linux-headers-virtual but simply linux-headers so `sudo apt-get install linux-headers` which may end up giving you a choice of specific available candidates you can pick.